# Arithmetic operators overload for R6classes in R

Tags: r, operator-overloading, r-package, r6

I am working on a custom `R6Class` which will be the main structure of my R package. But the problem is that this:

```
setMethod('+', signature("MyClass"), function(e1, e2)1)
```

or

```
setMethod('+', signature("R6"), function(e1, e2)1)
```

are not working because when I run

```
a = MyClass$new()
a + a
```

I get the following error `Error in a + a : non-numeric argument to binary operator`

The only way I got it working is like this

```
`+.MyClass` = function(e1, e2) { return (1) }
```

but this is not useful since when load the package from scratch (`library(MyClass)`) on an empty environment `+.MyClass` is not defined.

So, how can operators for R6 classes be overloaded the right way?

*Just in case, the snippet*:

```
MyClass = R6Class(
   "MyClass",
   public = list(
      initialize = function() {
      }
   ),
   private = list(
   )
)

setMethod('+', signature("MyClass"), function(e1, e2)1)
a = MyClass$new()
a+a
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you load the package, `+.MyClass` should absolutely be available, assuming you've exported the function.<sup>1</sup>

I can demonstrate this with a minimal example, for which I used [`devtools`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/devtools/index.html) -- I can't recommend enough the use of devtools for package creation. First, I create a minimal package structure:

```
devtools::create("dummypack", rstudio = FALSE)
```

Then I add a single R file in the "dummypack/R/" folder, "MyClass.R":

```
#' @export
MyClass = R6::R6Class(
    "MyClass",
    public = list(
        initialize = function() {
        }
    ),
    private = list(
    )
)

#' @export
`+.MyClass` = function(e1, e2) { return (1) }
```

The `#' @export` tags here are critical;<sup>2</sup> what you need for this function to be available is that it is *exported* in the "dummypack/NAMESPACE" file (see [the Namespaces chapter](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/namespace.html#exports) of Hadley Wickham's R packages). You need your NAMESPACE file to look like

```
export(MyClass)
export(`+.MyClass`)
```

to make sure *both* the class and the overloaded `+` operator are exported. Alternatively you could have a NAMESPACE like

```
exportPattern("^[^\\.]")
```

to export everything that does not begin with a `.` (this is the NAMESPACE file initially generated by `devtools::create()`). So, if you are *not* using `devtools` (and Roxygen -- [`roxygen2`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/roxygen2/index.html)), you need to edit the NAMESPACE file yourself to make sure your functions are exported.

Then I run

```
devtools::install("dummypack/")
```

and in a fresh R session I run:

```
library(dummypack)
a = MyClass$new()
a+a
# [1] 1
```

to show that you get the result you'd want.

---

1 <sub>I would have thought this question could be easily marked as a duplicate. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18620697/functions-not-loaded-from-homebuilt-package) was the closest I found, but seemed to be a little too Roxygen-specific.</sub>

2 <sub>Note that those tags only help with your NAMESPACE file if you are using Roxygen (which would work if you were using `devtools::document()`). Also, for the minimal example I show, the tags aren't technically necessary since the default NAMESPACE generated by `devtools::create()` just has the line `exportPattern("^[^\\.]")` as discussed above. However, in the typical case you want these tags and either way the important thing is what ends up in the NAMESPACE file -- you need explicit `export()` statements in NAMESPACE or a statement such as `exportPattern("^[^\\.]")`.</sub>

Comment: Thanks! I was using exportPattern("^[[:alpha:]]+").